# In Python 2, how do I create several new lists that differ by changes to the first element?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have two two lists (mylist and myline). I want to add each element of mylist to the first element of myline, such that for each element in mylist I get a new myline where myline[0] = mylist[x] + "_" + myline[0]. For example:

```
mylist = ["a","b","c"]
myline = ["blah", "jah", "hah"]
```

I want to get in return:

```
["a_blah", "jah", "hah"]
["b_blah", "jah", "hah"]
["c_blah", "jah", "hah"]
```

But when I run the following code, it doesn't work:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> mylist = ["a","b","c"]
>>> myline = ["blah", "jah", "hah"]
>>> for x in mylist:
...     print x
...
a
b
c
>>> for x in mylist:
...     secondline = myline
...     secondline[0] = x + "_" + myline[0]
...     print x
...     print myline
...     print secondline
...
a
['a_blah', 'jah', 'hah']
['a_blah', 'jah', 'hah']
b
['b_a_blah', 'jah', 'hah']
['b_a_blah', 'jah', 'hah']
c
['c_b_a_blah', 'jah', 'hah']
['c_b_a_blah', 'jah', 'hah']
>>>
```

It seems that myline gets changed as well, even though I never specifically change myline (I always create a new "secondline" based on "myline"). I've been trying to figure this out and I feel like I'm going to lose my mind! Where am I going wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you *do* change **myline**.  You made **secondline** a virtual reference to the original, so they point to the same object.  the easy way to copy a sequence (list, tuple, string, etc.) is with

```
secondline = myline[:]
```

Try that.

Comment: Thanks @Prune ! I can't believe I didn't know about this.

Comment: You're welcome.  See the duplicate reference for excellent answers.  I didn't find the link in time.